# installing app : MADGRAPH

Tags: tar

in order to installing MadGraph,which is a physicist app showing Feynmman digrams for production of particles, I have download a version,then I have try to untar it using

```
$ tar zxvf MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz
```

my working directory shows:

```
tar (child): MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz : open impossible: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

any help, please

Comment: No such file or folder : Include the path to MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz → `tar xvf [path to directory with]/MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz`

Comment: thanks a lot , it is on desktop; can you tell me what shall I write instead [path to directory]

Comment: OK, your location is Desktop/  ( Please check location with the `pwd` command.) ... Then do `tar xvf ../Downloads/ MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz` ... i.e. if your MG5 package is located in `Downloads/`

Comment: @KnudLarsen ,I can't express my gratitude to you, Now it is  work; thank you veery much for your help

Comment: @KnudLarsen , there is a little probleme after using: $ cd MG5_aMC_v2_7_0, terminal show: ~/MG5_aMC_v2_7_0$ ;then after using: $ ./bin/mg5_aMC ;this to start MG5_aMC shell: MG5_aMC> ; but my terminal show: :~/MG5_aMC_v2_7_0$ ./bin/mg5_aMC
/usr/bin/env: «python»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: A valid python 2.7, see the file install : "Python 2.6 (or higher, but not compatible with 3.X" ... I.e. required is `/usr/bin/python` ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4fi2ya9njycms6/mg5_aMC__trerminal-text.txt?dl=0

Comment: @KnudLarsen How can I install python 2.6 or highe and gfortran ?

Comment: This is the Ubuntu ask and answer site. So I guess you have some version of Ubuntu ? Which one ? .... Install python 2.7 : `sudo apt install python gfortran` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python

Comment: @Knud , Yes, it is Ubuntu 17.10, which package you advice me to install?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 (unsupported version) : It's also `sudo apt install python gfortran` ... ( If you can. 'apt' depends on /usr/bin/python, so it's an error that it isn't there.)

Comment: @Knud ,I downloaded python2.7_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2_amd64.deb and gfortran-6-x86-64-linux-gnux32_6.4.0-17ubuntu1cross1_amd64(2).deb.part, and try the command 'code' sudo apt install python gfortran; then appears:  
Aucune version du paquet python n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base
de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète
ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source

E: Le paquet « python » n'a pas de version susceptible d'être installée
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet gfortran

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> installing app, MADGRAPH: $ tar zxvf MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz
>
> tar (child): MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz : open impossible : No such file or
> folder

No such file or folder : Include the path to MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz

```
tar xvf [path to directory with]/MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz
```

Ref. comment : Your location is Desktop/ ( Please check location with the `pwd` command.) Then please do

```
tar xvf ../Downloads/MG5_aMC_v2.7.0.tar.gz
```

I.e. if your MG5 package is located in Downloads/

---

Ref. comment Feb 26 2020 :
Please update the package list →

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall python
sudo apt install gfortran
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tar.gz` seems to be broken and can't be unpacked. Maybe there was a glitch while you downloaded it, or it has been broken some other way. You need to get a new, fresh copy.

I don't know about MADGRAPH, but for many apps you can get checksums. You download the package, compute the checksum and compare it with the checksum the package *should* have. Those checksums are typically hashes built with algorithms like SHA-256. For example, Anaconda has [the correct checksums listed on their website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-ppc64le.sh-hash/).

To compute the checksum for the file you downloaded, you can use a tool like `md5sum`, `sha256sum` or similar, depending on the algorithm used.